# What is the equivalent of `ss` for Mac?

Tags: command-line

I want a command-line tool to inspect sockets, like [`ss`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) for Linux, but for Mac. Is there a port of that tool, or another tool I could use for Mac OS systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of ss for Mac OSX is netstat, part of Network Utility.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202790

Comment: From netstat man page: This program is obsolete.  Replacement for netstat is ss.   Replacement for  netstat -r is ip route.  Replacement for netstat -i is ip -s link. Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr.

Comment: Your links busted.

Comment: the netstat man page on OS X is different :) and doesn't say obsolete. 
 lsof may be another option: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157893/what-is-the-equivalent-of-netstat-tln-on-os-x